# Screenshot in form file (js?)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

There is possibility to let user to make screenshot of actual window and put it into form? The object is some div with map if it's helpful.

Thanks for all of answers.

Comment: yes, you can have the user press [PrtScr] and then paste into a content editable div, capturing the paste event to grab the image data. i don't think most devs realize that's possible...

Comment: Ye, i was trying HTML2Canvas, but that library cant make screenshot of for example google maps :/

Comment: i found something: http://jsfiddle.net/wemxxfgo/5/ but still its downloading file instead putting it into file by php